# Как экранировать символы в запросе MS SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Имеется программа на С#, работающая с MS SQL Server:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tests where Name='" + oldValue + "'", connection);
    SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (read.HasRows)
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(read.GetString(0));
            command = new SqlCommand("update Tests set Name='" + oldValue + "' where Id = " + read.GetString(0), connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    } 
 }
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что, если в ячейке таблицы имеется строковое значение, включающее скобки (в моём случае), то результатом `SELECT`'а является пустой запрос. Судя по всему, скобки - это какой-то спецсимвол. Это, естественно, не даёт сделать то, что мне надо.

Вопрос: нет ли какой-то функции или способа экранирования спецсимволов в запросе? В поисковиках не смог найти ничего внятного.

Answer (score 7):

Мне непонятна логика Ваших SQL запросов, но будем считать, что это погрешности переноса кода из проекта в SO.

Используйте параметризованные запросы и горя не знайте:

```
SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tests where Name=@Name", connection);
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", oldValue);
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("update Tests set Name=@Name where Id = @Id", connection);
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", oldValue);
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", reader.GetString(0));
    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

NB: Последний раз, когда я это проверял, `SqlConnection` с открытым ридером нельзя было использовать для других операций.

Comment: Давно проверяли - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars

Comment: @PashaPash - ох давно :)

Comment: Не помогает: http://i.imgur.com/jjogDHj.png

Comment: @Byulent У Вас на картинке на какой строчке остановлено исполение кода - `int s = ...`?

Comment: @Igor На следующей.

Comment: @Byulent Kaк же Вы, интересно, туда попали, если считаете, что в ридере нет записей? Зачем нужна проверка `reader.HasRows`, если, в случае пустого результата запроса, код просто не зайдет в `while`?

Comment: @Igor Там есть ещё одна ветка, которую я не написал.

Comment: Ещё вот в чём дело: если не использовать перед строкой символ `N`, то `HasRows` равно True, даже если никаких записей там нет. Если использовать его, то всё выполняется как надо.